# Elixir: Best practice to wrap a timed state inside a GenServer?

Tags: caching, elixir, webserver, phoenix-framework

I came from a game development background and have little experience with web servers.

I'm developing a web server based on Elixir/Phoenix. Say we have some players that can join guilds. The relationship between `Guild` and `Player` is one-to-many. In order to boost up the performance, we want to cache data in memory as much as possible, so we cache data of players and also guilds. But since players may "share" the same guilds, we attempt to wrap the guild data into a GenServer, so that every operation for a single guild can be performed sequentially.

With the design mentioned above, we realized that caching for the guild became a little bit tricky to deal with. Since every guild itself is a separate process, what process is in charge of expiring the guild process?

- If the guild process is in charge of expiring itself, every cast/call message sent after the expiration could not be successfully run.
- If we have a `GuildManager` to manage all the expiration logic for the guild processes. Kill a guild process would also cause every guild-pid-holder process to crash.

So what's the best practice to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: There are tons of solutions: trapping exits in parents, registry of guilds alive, graceful termination of guilds, watchdogs after all, but it is impossible to tell which one is mostly applicable here without seeing the real code.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin We don't have the actual code for now, as we're still in the design phase. We wanna know the best practice to design around such "shared state" (guild) situation.

Comment: I agree with @AlekseiMatiushkin that there are many ways you can do this, and "the best way" mostly depends on your context.
A common solution is to have a `DynamicSupervisor` of games (or guilds) which is used to manage (start and stop) the games' life-cycle (you can avoid restarts with `:temporary` restart option). 
To implement the expiration, at the beginning you could simply use the GenServer [timeout](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-timeouts).